# Renaming value names in AWS Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

[image]

Is it possible to rename value names in AWS Quicksight without renaming the field in the source dataset? For example below I would like to rename the 'Amount' value to 'Sales' for this visual only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can rename the ledger name for one particular visual. Quick alternatives would be to create a Calculated field and rename it to sales.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this would be to change the field name. If the field name is a calculated field:

1. In your analysis 'Field list', find the field you wish to use and click the three dots to the right of the field name
2. Click 'Edit calculated field'
3. At the top, edit the name of the calculated field to what you want it to read in the legend
4. Click 'Save'

If it is a non-calculated field:

1. Go into your 'Data Prep' and locate the dataset you are using
2. Find the name of the field you wish to use and click the three dots to the right of the field name
3. Click 'Edit name & description'
4. A text box will appear and you can change the title and description of the field

In both field instances, the legend elements will be updated. See screenshots below!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hsj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMqBZ.png

Answer (score 0):

Very annoying but it does not seem to be an option.  Field names are defined in the dataset and the names are locked in globally.

While ugly, you can always create a calculated field that passthroughs the value of the column.  You can then provide a different name for this field and reference it in your visualization.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on your view on the panel
2. Click the pensil (Format Visual)
3. go to value names and edit it there